# How can I insert the first 8 characters of a GUID into a colum when a new row is created?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL server table in my database.

There is a column named `Code` in a table called `Admin`.

How can I make this default to the first 8 characters of a GUID?  Note that this column is a varchar(8).

Comment: Try this - `SELECT LEFT(NEWID(), 8)`. I think this is what you want..

Comment: Can you tell me how I can make it so this is the default for the column ?

Comment: Note that the first 8 characters of a GUID aren't guaranteed to be unique, so it might happen that multiple rows in that table have the same `Code`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_table_myColumn] DEFAULT(left(newid(), (8)))
    FOR [myColumn]
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

While Alter table

```
ALTER TABLE ADMIN 

ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT LEFT(NEWID(), 8) FOR Code;
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE ADMIN 

ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT RIGHT(NEWID(), 8) FOR Code;
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE ADMIN 

ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() as VARCHAR(50)),1,8 ) FOR Code;
```

While Creating Table

```
CREATE TABLE ADMIN(
Code varchar(8)
 CONSTRAINT DF_PurchaseOrderDetail_rowguid DEFAULT
 LEFT(NEWID(), 8) FOR Code
 )
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE ADMIN(
Code varchar(8)
 CONSTRAINT DF_PurchaseOrderDetail_rowguid DEFAULT
 RIGHT(NEWID(), 8) FOR Code
 )
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE ADMIN(
Code varchar(8)
 CONSTRAINT DF_PurchaseOrderDetail_rowguid DEFAULT
 SUBSTRING(CAST(NEWID() as VARCHAR(50)),1,8 ) FOR Code
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a default constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Admin] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Admin_Code]  
DEFAULT (substring(CONVERT([varchar](50),newid(),0),(1),(8))) FOR [Code]
```